# Mongoose object field assignment not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to update a limited number of results, for that I have the following code:

```
// `places` variable is a `.find` result
async.mapSeries(places, function(p, msCallback){
    if(!p.stats){
        p.stats = { 'impressions': 0 }
    }
    if(!p.stats.impressions){
        p.stats.impressions = 0
    }

    // This is what I want to update
    p.stats.impressions += 1

    console.log(p.stats) // { views: 10, pulse: 30, impressions: 0 }

    p.save(function(e){
        // Never logged
        if(e) log('[places][_in] No se ha actualizado la impresión', 'error')
        // Always logged
        console.log('Saved') // Saved
        return msCallback()
    })
}, function(err){
    // Never logged
    if(err) log('[places][_in] Error al actualizar impresión')
    return sCallback(null, places)
})
```

Note: Every place in the database has the field `stats.impressions` with value `0`

**UPDATE:**
Also tried with `forEach`

```
places.forEach(function(p){
    if(!p.stats){
        p.stats = { 'impressions': 0 }
    }
    if(!p.stats.impressions){
        p.stats.impressions = 0
    }
    p.stats.impressions += 1
    log(p.stats)
    p.save(function(e){
        if(e) log('[places][_in] No se ha actualizado la impresión', 'error')
        log('Guardado')
    })
})
```

**SOLVED**

The field in the model was different (missed the ending `s`):

```
'stats': {
    // Lots of stat fields
    'impression': { type: Number, default: 0 }
```

Comment: can you also post your schema of the mongoose model, it may have something to do with that.

Comment: @HenryLiu That's it! Field in my model was `impression` instead of `impressions`. I was going crazy with this thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging i would add logging the saved object in the save callback also log the error e because if there is an error i think yu would like to know which error. Im also not sure why you don't call the save operation on the actual item to save like place.save()

```
save(function(e,val){
    // Never logged
    if(e) console.log(e)
    // Log here your new saved Item
    if(val)console.log(val)
    // Always logged  
    console.log('Saved') // Saved
    return msCallback()
})
```

Comment: I call the item `save` method, editing error. Sorry for that.

Comment: did you tried to log the object in the save? is it printed correctly